# Android Studio: Error "No target device" and the files and packages under project all are marked red

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

1. In the project view on the left, all the files are marked red. But when I run the project in AVD, it runs normally. Does the red sign have any impact?
2. When I connect my phone to Android Studio, it can't found my device. Instead it shows:

> Error running app:No target device found.

This is the screenshot of my project:

[image: this is the issue]

Comment: Just to make sure, have you cleaned and rebuilt the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,you project added vcs,but the files no added.  so the files is red.you could add this files into vcs,if you use git,you could run "git add ."

2,you could restart your AS or pc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, which is useful for me. I solved the two problems. And the second problem is the device's reason, I used other android device, it can connect, and work.My English is not well, take some trouble for your  reading,please accept my apology and thanks your suggest again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, just opened new project or if you have git pull the project again. some problem with the cradle and links in the project.